# Symfony 2.1 error: import @ORM\Table in repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I am upgrading an application from Symfony 2.0 to Symfony 2.1, I followed [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) upgrade file and all works fine except that after a `cache:clear` I get an error when using some repositories. Here is the error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@ORM\Table" in class 
edasiclinic\AlertesBundle\Repository\AlertesRepository was never imported. Did you maybe
forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

This is one example, I get this error with other repositories. I don't understand why I have to import `@ORM\Table` inside a repository file if I don't use annotation there.

Also if I wait for ~10 seconds and then refresh the browser, it works...

**EDIT**

This is the Entity:

```
<?php

namespace edasiclinic\DatabaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * edasiclinic\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Alertes
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="alertes")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="edasiclinic\AlertesBundle\Repository\AlertesRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Alertes
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="idAlerta", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

And this the repository class:

```
<?php

namespace edasiclinic\AlertesBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use edasiclinic\DasiBundle\Funcions\AES;


class AlertesRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function countUnread($user, $idioma, $fus)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM` at the top?

Comment: In the entity (that use this repository class) yes, but in the repository no. I don't import the `orm\mapping` in any repository

Comment: If you are using the `@ORM` annotation then, as far as I know, you should be importing the mapping jobby.

Comment: I'm using it in a listener on a `kernel.request`, maybe it is called before it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a PHP bug in versions prior to 5.3.8. From the [symfony system requirements](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/SymfonyRequirements.php#L546-L548):

```
$this->addRecommendation(
    version_compare($installedPhpVersion, '5.3.8', '>='),
    'When using annotations you should have at least PHP 5.3.8 due to PHP bug #55156',
    'Install PHP 5.3.8 or newer if your project uses annotations.'
);
```

See [PHP bug #55156](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55156) for more details and possible workaround if you're unable to upgrade to a PHP version >= 5.3.8.

Answer (score 3):

I had this very same problem today. the solution, after some googling, is apparently to include a comment block before the Repository class definition.

in your case:

```
/**
 * AlertesRepository 
 */
class AlertesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  ...
}
```

without that comment block, you will receive the nonsensical error about "@ORM\Table". yet another Symfony/Doctrine oddity >_>

Comment: Yep, that works! I solved it months ago by adding the use of ORM\Mapping to the repo class, but I prefer this solution. Still I don't know why I get this error :S

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to add the `use` statement.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;

// Remember to include this use statement
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * My Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntityRepository")
 */
class MyEntity
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it only hapens with certain versions of PHP and the solution was to put the Repository class in a folder above the folder of entity class